# Unable to find the object manager associated with an entity of class "SomeBundle\Folder\SomeClass"

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Using Symfony 2.7, I am trying to create a user registration form. I've used [Symfony's own guide](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/registration_form.html) for this, and the form is rendered and fillable.

When I fill in the form, and press "Register", I get the following error.

```
Unable to find the object manager associated with an entity of class "UserBundle\Models\User"
```

This is triggered on the following condition in `vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Validator/Constraints/UniqueEntityValidator.php at line 75`

```
$em = $this->registry->getManagerForClass(get_class($entity));
        if (!$em) {
            throw new ConstraintDefinitionException(sprintf('Unable to find the object manager associated with an entity of class "%s".', get_class($entity)));
        }
```

In the createAction in my UserController, the Entity Manager is fetched by `$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();` as per the instructions in the Symfony Cookbook.

I can't find out what's going here. Any help appreciated!

Also, please let me know if there is some information missing that I should have provided.

Comment: How did you create the entity? Do you have a configuration file which tells doctrine how to map that entity to your database?

Comment: @skrilled - No, that doesn't ring a bell. Is there a cookbook entry for this? I mean, it might exist already, but if so, I haven't done anything with it.

Comment: If you are using the cookbook method you would run `app/console doctrine:generate:entity` as this would create your initial entity file, the mapping file, and everything else to automatically let doctrine manage the new entity. There are a variety of other commands to quickly generate stuff like this, just run `app/console` from the directory to get a full list of what's available.

Comment: Looking at getManagerForClass possibly it's some sort of namespacing issue.

Comment: Can you post your user class please?

Comment: @Richard - I pastebinned it. I feel like it would clutter the question since it's rather big. It's pretty much as in the CookBook except I've opted for "User" instead of "Account": http://pastebin.com/z181AfRJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think unless you specifically map a directory in your config, doctrine is going to look in YourBundle/Entity - this is where your User.php example diverges from the cookbook recipe.

If you want to change this you'll need to specify it explicitly as per [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#mapping-configuration)

Alternatively just shift your User model to \Entity instead of \Models and I think it'll be OK.