# Unable to find the object manager associated with an entity of class

Tags: symfony, doctrine, fosuserbundle

I am developing an application with symfony 2.8 with the bundle "FOSUSERBUNDLE", my problem is when I try to register a user, I can see the registration form, but when registering I throw the following error:

> Unable to find the object manager associated with an entity of class
>   "Alienigena\ViviendaBundle\Entity\User".

I follow step by step the official tutorial of "FOSUSERBUNDLE", my USER class is:

```
namespace Alienigena\ViviendaBundle\Entity; 
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser; 
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**  
* @ORM\Entity  
* @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")  
*/ 
class User extends BaseUser {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    } 
}
```

Comment: please add your config code

Comment: yes add the configuration of fosuserbundle  here

Comment: My file config.yml is: 

https://pastebin.com/zTMFcT9Y

Comment: open composer.json and tell me fosuserbundle version

Comment: In my file composer.json my version of fosuserbundle is:         "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev"

Comment: I suggest you to uninstall 2 version by ' composer remove   "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle" ' and remove config and appkernel registration then try with 1.3 version

Comment: ok, it has me desperate, I have not found the solution for many hours, try with version 2.0 and the result was the same.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not understand the solution granted in this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31550187/unable-to-find-the-object-manager-associated-with-an-entity-of-class-somebundle

Comment: in this question he's not using fosuserbundle, have you tried 1.3 version?

Comment: hi, install version 1.3 of fosuserbundle and the problem is the same. What would you recommend me to try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem originated because at the moment of mapping the bd with reverse engineering I did with the mapping in xml, I should have mapped it with annotations. 
the solution consisted in eliminating the files with extension xml that were generated with the inverse engineering.

Thanks