# FosUserBundle: Unable to find the object manager associated with an entity of class "AppBundle\Entity\User"

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

Over my symfony 3.4 project I have the following user entity:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Misd\PhoneNumberBundle\Validator\Constraints\PhoneNumber as AssertPhoneNumber;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your name.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min=3,
     *     max=25,
     *     minMessage="The name is too short.",
     *     maxMessage="The name is too long.",
     *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
     * )
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your name.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min=3,
     *     max=25,
     *     minMessage="The surname is too short.",
     *     maxMessage="The surname is too long.",
     *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
     * )
     */
    protected $surname;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="phone_number")
     * @AssertPhoneNumber
     */
    protected $phone;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min=0,
     *     max=255,
     *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
     * )
     */
    protected $organization;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min=0,
     *     max=255,
     *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
     * )
     */
    protected $occupation;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function setName(string $name): User
    {
      $this->name=$name;

      return $this;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }


    public function setSurname(string $surname): User
    {
      $this->surname=$surname;

      return $this;
    }

    public function getSurname()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setPhone($phoneNum): User
    {
      $this->phone=$phoneNum;

      return $this;
    }

    public function getPhone()
    {
      return $this->phone;
    }

    public function setOrganization($organization): User
    {
      $this->organization=$organization;
      return $this;
    }

    public function getOrganization()
    {
      return $this->organization;
    }

    public function setOccupation($occupation): User
    {
      $this->occupation=$occupation;
      return $this;
    }

    public function getOccupation()
    {
      return $this->occupation;
    }

}
```

I also extended the form accordingly:

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Misd\PhoneNumberBundle\Form\Type\PhoneNumberType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;


class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name',TextType::class,["label"=>"register.name","required"=>true,'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'])
                ->add('surname',TextType::class,["label"=>"register.surname","required"=>true,'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'])
                ->add('phone',PhoneNumberType::class,["label"=>"register.phonenum","required"=>false,'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'])
                ->add('organization',TextType::class,["label"=>"register.organization","required"=>false,'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'])
                ->add('occupation',TextType::class,["label"=>"register.position","required"=>false,'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle']);
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType';
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'app_user_registration';
    }

    // For Symfony 2.x
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->getBlockPrefix();
    }
}
```

Also the extended form for my resistration is the following:

```
{% extends "@FOSUserBundle/layout.html.twig" %}
{% block title %} Register {% endblock title %}

{% block fos_user_content %}

  {% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}

  <div class="row clearfix"><div class="col"><h1 style="text-align:center">{{ 'register.title'|trans }}</h1></div></div>
  <div class="row clearfix">
    {{ form_start(form, {'method': 'post', 'action': path('fos_user_registration_register'), 'attr': {'class': 'fos_user_registration_register col'}}) }}
      {% include "@FOSUser/Registration/register_content.html.twig" %}
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col">
          <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" name="acceptTerms" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck">{{ 'register.acceptTerms'|trans }}</label>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="{{ 'registration.submit'|trans }}" />
      </div>
    {{ form_end(form) }}
  </row>

{% endblock fos_user_content %}
```

I also have looked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31550187/unable-to-find-the-object-manager-associated-with-an-entity-of-class-somebundle) and this piece of [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/configuration/doctrine.html) But still I get no fix even though I have the following configuration for my orm:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        server_version: 5.7
        host: '%database_host%'
        port: '%database_port%'
        dbname: '%database_name%'
        user: '%database_user%'
        password: '%database_password%'
        charset: UTF8
        types:
            phone_number: Misd\PhoneNumberBundle\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\PhoneNumberType

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            AppBundle:
               type: annotation
               dir: 'Entity'
               is_bundle: true
               prefix: AppBundle\Entity
               alias: AppBundle
```

But I get the following error:

> Unable to find the object manager associated with an entity of class "AppBundle\Entity\User".

I also have looked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31550187/unable-to-find-the-object-manager-associated-with-an-entity-of-class-somebundle) without any light towards to the solution.

Do you know why that happens and how I can fix it?

## Edit 1

I also tried to put the following doctrine configuration without any desired result:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        server_version: 5.7
        host: '%database_host%'
        port: '%database_port%'
        dbname: '%database_name%'
        user: '%database_user%'
        password: '%database_password%'
        charset: UTF8
        types:
            phone_number: Misd\PhoneNumberBundle\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\PhoneNumberType

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            AppBundle:
               type: annotation
               dir: 'Entity'
               is_bundle: true
               prefix: AppBundle\Entity
               alias: AppBundle
            FOSUserBundle:
               type: xml
               dir:  Resources/config/doctrine-mapping
```

### Edit 2

As requested my settings for `fos_user` are:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb' and 'couchdb'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
    service:
        mailer: fos_user.mailer.twig_swift
    from_email:
        address: "%mailer_user%"
        sender_name: "%mailer_user%"
    registration:
      form:
        type: AppBundle\Form\RegistrationType
```

Comment: Could you show your config for `fos_user`?

Comment: You are missing the `@ORM\Entity` annotation on your model. Is that a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you placed @ORM\Entity at the `AppBundle\Entity\User`?

As @dbrumann mentions you missing that into your `AppBundle\Entity\User`

So the class should defines like that:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Misd\PhoneNumberBundle\Validator\Constraints\PhoneNumber as AssertPhoneNumber;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your name.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min=3,
     *     max=25,
     *     minMessage="The name is too short.",
     *     maxMessage="The name is too long.",
     *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
     * )
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your name.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min=3,
     *     max=25,
     *     minMessage="The surname is too short.",
     *     maxMessage="The surname is too long.",
     *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
     * )
     */
    protected $surname;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="phone_number")
     * @AssertPhoneNumber
     */
    protected $phone;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min=0,
     *     max=255,
     *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
     * )
     */
    protected $organization;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min=0,
     *     max=255,
     *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
     * )
     */
    protected $occupation;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function setName(string $name)
    {
      $this->name=$name;

      return $this;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }


    public function setSurname(string $surname)
    {
      $this->surname=$surname;

      return $this;
    }

    public function getSurname()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setPhone($phoneNum)
    {
      $this->phone=$phoneNum;

      return $this;
    }

    public function getPhone()
    {
      return $this->phone;
    }

    public function setOrganization($organization)
    {
      $this->organization=$organization;
      return $this;
    }

    public function getOrganization()
    {
      return $this->organization;
    }

    public function setOccupation($occupation)
    {
      $this->occupation=$occupation;
      return $this;
    }

    public function getOccupation()
    {
      return $this->occupation;
    }
}
```